# proof that the dimension of a subspace is less than or equal to the dimension of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and let $U$ be a subspace of $V$.
I'm trying to prove that $\dim (U) \leq \dim (V)$, but I'm not sure if the  arguments what I gave was enough. Please take a look at it:
I supposed for the sake of contradiction that $\dim(U)>\dim(V)$, then I tried to write basis for both spaces $U$ and $V$ as $B_u=\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_m\}$ and $B_v=\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ (respectively), where $m>n$. So, that means $B_u$ contains $m$ linearly independent vectors and $B_v$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors. Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$ then $V$ contains $m$ linearly independent vectors. On the other hand, $B_v$ already contains all linearly independent vectors of $V$ which are $n$. Here is the contradiction.

Comment: This result is one for which a good proof depends on what you already know about linearly independent sets.

Comment: Contradiction seems unnecessarily confusing. Start with a basis for $U$. What is the natural question to ask?